# Understandable basic thing on NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, routes

My domain is : izio.fr
I have an Express application based on Router() (the one availible by Express)
I have this basic code :

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    console.log("TEST")
    return res.send("OK")
})
```

my application is configurated to listen on the 8080 port :

```
httpsServer.listen(port, function () {
    return console.log('Socialify server listening on %s at port %d in %s mode', host, port, env);
});
```

where port is 8080.

I go on chrome, I type izio.fr:8080/ and it redirects to izio.fr(:80) and the server doesn't respond.

But this route works fine:

```
router.route("/test").
    get(function(req, res, next){
        console.log("TEST")
        res.send("<h1> TEST </h1>")
    })
```

Even if my router doesn't work, I enable the static on my app. So izio.fr:8080/index.html works but not the izio.fr:8080/ ? How's that possible?

Answer (score 0):

For example Route methods

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
})
```

file `index.html` in `yourApp/src/public/index.html`

Read more https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Either explicitly hardcode your code to use the port you want, like:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

You should define static folder in your server for to give server access your static file

```
app.use(
  "/static",
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public"))
);
```

This folder in `yourApp/src/public`

```
app.use(
  "/static",
  express.static("/public"))
);
```

This folder in `yourApp/public`

You can read more at https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: I already done this : app.use(express.static('/var/www')) and this : app.set('port', port) where port = 8080 just 5 lines upper

Comment: `app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/var/www/index.html'));
})`
for `izio.fr:8080/` work for index.html

Comment: I tried, but izio.fr:8080/ redirect me to izio.fr(:80) even if I do this

Comment: `app.set('port', 8080);`
to set port you want to use this shound on top of index.js and bottom import

Comment: "app.set('port', port) where port = 8080 just 5 lines upper", I already done this, while other pages works

Comment: can you post a code for index.js or path of app.set('port')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166407/discussion-between-izio-and-thien-duy).